# How do I reinitialize a Kendo component when using Angular directives

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am using the Kendo Scheduler component but I want to reinitialize the scheduler because I have added a resource.  How do I go about reinitializing a kendo component with angular directives?

I tried:

```
$scope.MyScheduler.destroy();
$scope.MyScheduler.setOptions($scope.schedulerOptions);
$scope.MyScheduler.refresh();
```

The component does destroy but never gets recreated.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more googling I found the solution.  On the directive there's a rebind option:

So if you do something like this:

$scope.schedulerOptions = {mycooloptions};

It will rebuild your component with the new options.